# VBA Print Active Sheet Increment

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that copies some data to a sheet and afterwards make a copy to the end of the file.
The file is then  repoulated  with new data to be copied again to the end of the sheet.
That script work fine.
The only problem i have is that when i want to print out all sheets it start from the last one created instead of the first sheet.
So for exemple i have 60 sheets and when they are printed it start 60,59,58...1.

What can i do to make it print from page 1 to page 60 for exemple.

Thank you.

```
Sub Print_All()
    For i = 4 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        Worksheets(i).Select
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    Next
    i = i + 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For i = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count To 4 Step -1
```

Comment: Hm his code aside, you read the question text differently than me. I read that it is printing in reverse by default and he wants to print 1, 2, 3, ... 58, 59, 60. **Quote:** _problem ... is ... it start from the last one created instead of the first sheet_

Comment: @MarkBalhoff Per OP: *from the last one created instead of the first sheet. So for exemple i have 60 sheets and when they are printed it start __60,59,58...1__*

Comment: Thank you very much JohnyL it works perfectly. Have a great day ! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `For i = 1 to N`, then there is no need to go `i = i + 1` and it should work:

```
Sub PrintAll()

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Worksheets(i).PrintOut
    Next

End Sub
```

Furthermore, it is a good idea to avoid `Select` and `Activate` in VBA - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Thanky you for the improvement Vityata, i will read about avoiding select. Have a great day.